# Warning: Undefined array key / Warning: Attempt to read property "title" on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

When I try to go to checkout, I get these two messages

**Warning: Undefined array key 0 in /home4/iggcoomy/public_html/.website_a53b71d2/wp-content/plugins/paypalcurrencyconverterpro/paypalcc.php on line 1380**

**Warning: Attempt to read property "title" on null in /home4/iggcoomy/public_html/.website_a53b71d2/wp-content/plugins/paypalcurrencyconverterpro/paypalcc.php on line 1384**

```
public function ppcc_calculate_totals($totals)
{
    global $woocommerce;

    $available_gateways = $woocommerce->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
    
    if (!empty($available_gateways) && !is_cart()) {
        $current_gateway = $woocommerce->session->chosen_payment_method 
            ?? get_option('woocommerce_default_gateway') 
            ?? current($available_gateways)['id'];
        $current_gateway = $available_gateways[$current_gateway];
    }
    
    //check gateway
    if (strpos(strtolower($current_gateway->title), 'paypal') === false) {
        return;
    }

    //initialize   
    $options = get_ppcc_option('ppcc-options');
    $handling_fee = 0;
    $handling_fee_title = $options['handling_title'];

    //check tresholds
    $lower_treshold = $options['lower_treshold'] === 'on';
    $lower_treshold_amount = floatval($options['lower_treshold_amount']);
    $upper_treshold = $options['upper_treshold'] === 'on';
    $upper_treshold_amount = floatval($options['upper_treshold_amount']);

    //check handling percentage and fixed amount
    $handling_percentage = floatval($options['handling_percentage']);
    $handling_amount = floatval($options['handling_amount']);

    //start calculating dependant of settings
    $shipping_handling_fee = $options['shipping_handling_fee'] === 'on';
    $handling_taxable = $options['handling_taxable'] === 'on';
    $handling_fee_base = 0;
    if (!empty($totals)) {
        $handling_fee_base = $totals->cart_contents_total;
    }
```

[1380 & 1384](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CICxQ.png)

anyone can help me please? Thank you

when a customer goes to the payment page he receives these two warning messages, after refreshing the page they disappear I don't know why

Comment: Try: `$current_gateway = $woocommerce->session->chosen_payment_method 
?: get_option('woocommerce_default_gateway') ?? current($available_gateways)['id'];` or more safely: `$current_gateway = ($woocommerce->session->chosen_payment_method ?? NULL) ?: (get_option('woocommerce_default_gateway') ?? NULL) ?: current($available_gateways)['id'];`

Comment: no, it still doesn't work

Comment: Welcome! Do not edit this file. Contact the plugin developers support. Any changes you make will be lost once this plugin is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of errors and seems obsolete. Try the following simplified code version:

```php
public function ppcc_calculate_totals($totals)
{
    global $woocommerce;

    $current_gateway = $woocommerce->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    
    // Only allow PayPal gateway
    if (strpos($current_gateway, 'paypal') === false) {
        return; // Exit if it's not paypal
    }

    //initialize   
    $options = get_ppcc_option('ppcc-options');
    $handling_fee = 0;
    $handling_fee_title = $options['handling_title'];

    //check tresholds
    $lower_treshold = $options['lower_treshold'] === 'on';
    $lower_treshold_amount = floatval($options['lower_treshold_amount']);
    $upper_treshold = $options['upper_treshold'] === 'on';
    $upper_treshold_amount = floatval($options['upper_treshold_amount']);

    //check handling percentage and fixed amount
    $handling_percentage = floatval($options['handling_percentage']);
    $handling_amount = floatval($options['handling_amount']);

    //start calculating dependant of settings
    $shipping_handling_fee = $options['shipping_handling_fee'] === 'on';
    $handling_taxable = $options['handling_taxable'] === 'on';
    $handling_fee_base = 0;
    
    if (!empty($totals)) {
        $handling_fee_base = $totals->cart_contents_total;
    }

    // HERE add The rest of the code … 
}
```

It could work.